# Determining if specific lon/lat in various coordinate systems?

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg

I'm a newbie in `Gis` matter and don't want to make it very complex.
I want to plot a point somewhere and know it's lon/lat in some coordinate systems indicated by `EPSG` code.

I'm wanting to know if there is a website that provides a map, that we can plot a point on, and the website tells me for example: `this point is (lon=123456.123456, lat=456789.456789) in EPSG 32639 AND (lan=147.147, lat=369.369) in EPSG 3857 AND ...` ?

Or at least tells me **What EPSG is mostly used for this area/country**?

Comment: see also http://spatialreference.org/

Comment: Article in french: http://www.neogeo-online.net/blog/archives/17/

Comment: See the original EPSG website: http://www.epsg-registry.org and possibly http://epsg.io (not officially connected to the original EPSG site).

Comment: Bear in mind, that not all coordinate reference systems use degrees lat long.

Comment: @nmtoken would you please tell me a little more about it?

Comment: see http://epsg.io/3857 `Coordinate system: Cartesian 2D CS. Axes: easting, northing (X,Y). Orientations: east, north. UoM: m.`   So you can't  ever know the lon lat of a position **in EPSG::3857**  because  that coordinate system doesn't use degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit the EPSG.io website (the unofficial EPSG database website):

http://epsg.io/

[image: epsg.io]

If you search on this website for a country name or area name you get a list of coordinate systems used in there...

The web has also an interactive map to pick a place location in any of the supported coordinate systems:

http://epsg.io/map

[image: epsg.io map]

There is a Transform coordinates tool as well - for online transformation from one coordinate system to another:

http://epsg.io/transform

[image]

Enjoy! BTW we have developed this website for users of http://www.maptiler.com/. The EPSG.io is 100% open-source - available on GitHub: https://github.com/klokantech/epsg.io
You can also easily install it with Docker via https://hub.docker.com/r/klokantech/epsg.io/ and even use it off-line. It comes with search and transformation JSON APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this [site](http://twcc.fr/en/#).  Click on the question mark next to selected CRS and a pop up will give you the EPSG code.  And it lists country specific CRS's.

However, your question is a little bit open ended.  Each EPSG code has different applications and no website will give you a definitive answer for each country.